# I need multiple taglines in wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress

How can I use multiple taglines in Wordpress themes?

[image]

I've tried using the 'Advanced tagline' plugin, but it's not working properly.

Answer (score 0):

I'd first ask why does your site need multiple tag lines? If you want them in the title, then simply write as long as you want, but thats horrible UX.

I would otherwise go for Advanced Custom Fields, create an option field and then echo the content where-ever you want.

Comment: i want two line tag thats all.

Comment: how get the Advanced custom fields for echo the contents  , please give me the path for do that.

Comment: in Front Page of theme As that Title and tag Section

Comment: I would suggest using Advanced Custom Fields plug-in and go with my original solution so you'll have the ability add as many as you would like.